404 error accessing custom module in Perfex CRM
So i'm creating a PerfexCRM module that will be showing customer card transactions.
I'm trying to create the basics of the module before integrating API.
My problem is I get 404 page not found every time I try to access the client module front page cardportal_client/view_transactions. I can upload the plugin and activate it, but get an error when I try to access the link via the client front.
My file structure:
assets
 -js
 -css
cardportal.php
controllers
 - Cardportal_client.php
 - cardportal_admin.php
helpers
language
  - English
    - cardportal_lang.php
  - other_languages
models
  - cardportal_model.php
views
  - client_view.php

My cardportal.php
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

/**
 * Module Name: Card Portal
 * Description: A module for clients to view their card transactions in a grid view with filters.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Requires at least: 2.3.*
 */

// Example of adding a simple hook (if needed)
hooks()->add_action('admin_init', 'cardportal_init_menu_items');


hooks()->add_action('clients_init', 'cardportal_init_client_menu');

function cardportal_init_client_menu() {
    if (is_client_logged_in()) {
        add_theme_menu_item('cardportal-menu', [
            'name'     => 'Card Transactions',
            'href'     => site_url('cardportal_client/view_transactions'),  // Updated to the new method
            'position' => 10,
        ]);
    }
}

function cardportal_init_menu_items() {
    // Code to add menu items if necessary
}

$CI =& get_instance();
// Loading a custom library or helper if necessary
// $CI->load->library('cardportal/library_name');

cardportal_model.php:
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cardportal_model extends App_Model {
    public function get_transactions() {
        // Example function to get data
        return $this->db->get(db_prefix() . 'transactions')->result_array();
    }
}

Cardportal_client.php:
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cardportal_client extends Clients_controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // This ensures that only logged-in clients can access this controller
    }

    public function view_transactions() {
        $data['title'] = 'Card Transactions';
        $data['transactions'] = $this->get_client_transactions(); // Assume this method fetches transactions
        
        $this->data($data);
        $this->view('client_view'); // This view should be set up to display the transactions
        $this->layout();
    }

    private function get_client_transactions() {
        // For now, let's return a static array for display
        return [
            ['date' => '2021-01-01', 'amount' => '$100', 'description' => 'Transaction 1'],
            ['date' => '2021-01-02', 'amount' => '$200', 'description' => 'Transaction 2'],
            ['date' => '2021-01-03', 'amount' => '$300', 'description' => 'Transaction 3'],
        ];
    }
}

client_view.php:
<div class="container">
    <h2>Card Portal</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if (!empty($transactions)): ?>
                <?php foreach ($transactions as $transaction): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($transaction['date']); ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($transaction['amount']); ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($transaction['description']); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-center">No transactions found.</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

I have also added this line to the routes.php
/**
 * custom plugin
 */
$route['cardportal_client/view_transactions'] = 'cardportal_client/view_transactions';

